# what technology to use for a database service?

Tags: java, database, rest, soap, rpc

I am going to make a small trade management system. I want to make a independent database service to which all the other client connect. The database will be MYSQL and I will be using Java for making the service. The client can either be a Web Application or a desktop application using Java Swing (has not decided yet). There will be another layer sit between the client and the database service to handle the business logic (I call it trade service).

The architecture is something like: Client -> Trade Service -> Database Service.

My questions is that what client/service communication technology is the best suitable one for client->Trade Service and the best suitable one for Trade service -> Database.

Shall I make it s RESTful service? SOAP? Using RPC? Or any other technologies?

Many thanks for your help. Any idea or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What's the performance requirement?

Comment: Given the your requirements - why would you even want to establish a database service? I cannot see any valid reason for implementing this kind of abstraction layer. Btw: your clients should connect to the Trade Service and not the Database Service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RabbitMQ, A pool messaging service

http://www.rabbitmq.com/
It's Robust, flexible, fast and scalable and you can use it to communicate in Java, PHP, or whatever technologies ou want.

Answer (score 0):

> Shall I make it s RESTful service? SOAP? Using RPC?

These are all very similar approaches in that they are over HTTP so - assuming that's what you want; I would recommend using RESTful.  You'll have lot's of examples to work with and it will allow you flexibility in the future to do things like switching out the UI layer for a smart phone app or desktop app.

Regardless of what model you pick you should understand how it works first and build in things like security and guidelines early.  Do your homework now.  Trying to change the middle layer of a design like this is a pain.

Comment: SOAP and RPC don't have to run over HTTP

Answer (score 0):

There is no blanket answer to your question, there are instead options based on your skill set. Do you conceptually understand the HTTP spec completely and be able to extend it to REST, that works very closely with HTTP (common creation ancestor). Do you better understand the traditional method invocation of SOAP? Are you tied in your ecosystem to a specific language, as this can impact which tools you choose from.

If you were paying me to write a service based on the simple requirements you have given (which is nearly impossible), I would create a domain driven design service (your business layer) with a RESTful interface and Spring JDBC for data access. That is me, and what I work in most often. My partner in crime at work would probably choose SOAP and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're taking about is Queues, and I'm guessing you need a managed service for that. Queues can be the glue between your micro-services. Some of the vendors I know which have Queue as a Service are :

CloudBoost.io : https://www.cloudboost.io

Check out https://tutorials.cloudboost.io/en/queues/basicqueues for documentation.

Iron.io : https://www.iron.io

P.S : I work at CloudBoost